# CD4011BE (DUAL INPUT NAND GATE) not working

Tags: integrated-circuit, logic-gates, nand

[image][image]I am using my CD4011BE NAND Gate IC. I connected a 9V battery in the 14th pin. And grounded the 7th pin. Then I provided input in the first 2 pins. I took a 330 ohm resistor from the third pin and connected an LED with that resistor and then grounded the other side of the LED.

I checked every possible configurations of the 2 inputs {(0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(1,1)}.
But the outputs are not as expected. The LED never lights up.

I changed my IC and used another one of these CD4011BE and got surprised to see that this time the LED always lights up.

I am new to making circuits and electronics. So excuse my mistakes and please point them out.

Comment: Do you have pull-up resistors on the inputs? Or when you are giving it a '0' are you just leaving it? The issue could be to do with floating pins. Can you use the schematic editor to show us how you have set it up, and how you are providing a 1 or a 0 to the input?

Comment: When I am providing 0 I am grounding the input pin

Comment: Try using pull-up resistors on the inputs, and a switch to ground it. Do this on both inputs so you can toggle them separately, then see what happens

Comment: I firstly used switches. When I found them not working, then to simplify- I used simply jumper wires

Comment: Can you please draw a schematic and edit it into the question, along with a photo of the setup. That could be helpful

Comment: There is a circuit editor built into the site.  It often helps to draw a diagram rather than trying to describe your circuit with words.

Comment: I added my breadboard view

Comment: Thank you for adding the breadboard. Everything looks to be connected correctly, so the answer by @Hearth is looking more likely. Have you made sure the leg of the resistor hasn't shorted on the ground pin? And do you have a multimeter? The next thing to do would be measure the inputs and outputs

Comment: Fritzing **can** produce a schematic.  Without referring to the pinout for the 4011 from its datasheet, no one knows what those "first two pins" do.  A schematic diagram shows such details and makes it **much** easier to understand and discuss circuits.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of possible problems you could have had here.

As the 4000 series logic chips are based on FETs, it's rather easy to fry them with static electricity when touching them (antistatic wristbands are nice to have).

Secondly, are you sure you connected to the pins you thought you did? Maybe you had the chip turned around, or maybe you were off by one position.

Or perhaps you even just got immensely unlucky and got a bad chip from the factory. It doesn't happen often, but chip fabs aren't infallible.

Comment: I don't think so. This is exactly my first thought, but I re-read the last line to see that OP mentions the replacement IC had the LED *always* on, not that it was working, hence my asking for clarification on how the inputs are configured

Comment: @MCG Yeah, I reread that too and deleted the part where I suggested that they shouldn't worry because other ones are fine. It is still possible that they fried both chips with static; especially if these are old chips it's pretty easy to fry them inadvertently.

Comment: I connected the pins correctly.

Comment: The datasheet seem to indicate that the output current is only few mA, which is not going to work with the circuit OP described. Or I am reading some wrong data...

Comment: @EugeneSh. A few mA is enough to light up an LED, even one of the older types, enough to be visible. Sure, you won't illuminate a room with it, but it'll show you the output state unless I'm quite mistaken.

Comment: Yeah, the LED should at least illuminate slightly. It is very possible that the ICs were fried. We may know more with a photo of the setup and a schematic, which hopefully will get edited in to the question soon

Comment: After the breadboard and corresponding diagram were added, things look connected properly, so +1 now as this static damage or bad chips are looking more likely!